# How to change an icon color of InputDecoration with ThemeData?

Tags: flutter

The color property of iconThemeData in ThemeData does not applied for an Icon of InputDecoration.
How to apply icon color by ThemeData?

ThemeData

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(focusColor: Colors.white, labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    );
  }
```

TextFormField and InputDecoration

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(icon: const Icon(Icons.email), labelText: 'e-mail'),
),
```

[image]

Applied when set color on Icon class directory.

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(icon: const Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.white), labelText: 'e-mail'),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can change icon color by bellow way. Hope so you already solve this but someone will need this

```
InputDecoration buildInputDecoration(String hintText, IconData icon) {
  return InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(icon, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1.0)),
    // hintText: hintText,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
  );
}
```

access that

```
 decoration: buildInputDecoration("Confirm password", Icons.mobile_friendly, ),
```